# Python script runtime error - ImportToolbox and run a custom geoprocessing tool

Tags: arcpy, runtimeerror, toolbox

I am very new to Python.  I created a simple tool using Model Builder that updates a few columns of data in a SDE feature class.  The model runs perfectly within ArcMap 10.5.  I need this script to run automatically each night, and so I need a Python script to use in Windows Task Scheduler. Rather than exporting the model to a Python script from Model Builder (which I am aware does not always do a good job translating), I want to simply ask the script to run the tool.  I researched and attempted the 'ImportToolbox' function, but continue to get runtime/syntax errors.  I am not experienced enough to resolve what is going wrong.  I have tried different aliases, removing the alias altogether...nothing has eliminated the errors.  I am hoping someone will be able to point out where I may have gone wrong...

```
>>> import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"G:\tools\SIBToolbox.tbx","LCU")
arcpy.LaneClosureUpdate_LCU()
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 125, in ImportToolbox
    return import_toolbox(input_file, module_name)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox_code.py", line 457, in import_toolbox
    mymodule = generate_toolbox_module(toolbox, None, False, False, False, module_name, use_alt_alias)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox_code.py", line 432, in generate_toolbox_module
    'exec')
  File "G:\tools\SIBToolbox.tbx", line 11
    def LaneClosureUpdate.tbx():
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, have you tried the ImportToolbox statement without the second parameter module_name

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt response @artwork21!  If you are referring to removing the alias parameter, then yes.  I have tried to run it both with and without that and the result is the same.  The runtime error message concludes with a syntax error as well, and I have no idea what it doesn't like.